# Javascript gives false array length?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is below a screenshot of the Firefox debugger :

[image]

How is this possible ?

If it can help, I use this function:

```
function popElementTableau(tableau){
    if (tableau.length != 0){
        tableau[tableau.length-1].remove();
        tableau.pop();
    }
}
```

KR
Zlotz

PS for the person who closed my post: it doesn't seem related to [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays) because someone there mentions that "as of March 2016, this issue is no more"

Comment: The size of the array between when you logged it and when you expanded it.

Comment: Is it same for chrome?

Comment: Yes it's the same

Comment: What do you mean by "log the array'. I've used a breakpoint.